# Bash: Execute series of command from history

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I execute a series of commands from my bash history? 
For instance if I want to execute the commands numbered 34 to 42 in my bash history,
I've tried things like:

```
for n in $(seq 34 42); do
   exec \!$n;
done
```

but that doesn't really it do the the trick, does it. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I can think of is something like this.  Basically you pipe history into awk which prints lines with a number in a certain range.  The results are passed to a sub-shell.

```
history | awk '$1>32 && $1<42 {$1="";print substr($0,2)}' | bash
```

Somewhat based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110119/bash-history-without-line-numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that History (and the equivalent fc command) is disabled in scripting. I haven't found any documentation as to why though, the closest being the [tldp page explaining History and Bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/histcommands.html).